# SQL MERGE as substitute for INSERT - optimization

Tags: sql-server

I'm inserting tons of data into an SQL table and want to get generated ID's back. I need it work as fast as possible.

```
MERGE [TargetTable] AS dst USING [SourceTable] AS src 
ON 0 = 1 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN INSERT (...columns...) 
VALUES (...values)
```

I add data by 10K rows each time.
Once target table grows to 100M+ records, this operation now takes 2 to 300+ seconds.
By the actual execution plan most heavy operations are:

- Index Insert - 40%
- Clustered Index Merge - 20%
- Sort - 26%

Questions:

1. Is there a faster way to return ID's back when inserting chunks of data?
2. Does the MERGE still compare source and dest data even if I specify "0=1" which is never true? If so, then is there a way to prevent database engine from comparison data and always insert?
3. By the stats above, what should I do to descrease these latencies?

Comment: Maybe [parallel insert](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-parallel-insert-sql-server-2016-improve-query-performance/) `INSERT INTO [Target] WITH(TABLOCK)
SELECT * FROM [Source]`. Anyway you should show how you generate ID (IDENTITY/SEQUENCE). There ROW_NUMBER equivalent could be sometimes faster especially in DW scenarios. If you do it in daily basis you should consider table partitioning.

Comment: please upload the  actual execution plan - e.g. to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/